# 1 and multiplication form a group - Meaning?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I heard someone say this with respect to combinatorial mathematics, but I have no idea what they mean? Any ideas?

Comment: Some more context would be nice. In general, this statement is obviously not true, since $\mathbb N$ has both $1$ and multiplication....

Comment: Maybe he means the group $(\{1\},\cdot)$ which is of course isomorphic to the trivial group.

Comment: @Uncountable That sounds very likely, I didn't think of it like that. Still, without more context, we can't be sure...

Comment: It was meant to be a joke... It didn't register